# Is there a way to define named queries not within entity classes nor a package-info.java?

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

Is there a way to register at Hibernate the named queries that don't reside within entity classes or a package-info.java?

At the moment my named queries are defined by means of the annotations `org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery` wrapped in a`org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries` in package-info.java classes, but when a query is defined within a service class that is not entity, it should have the scope `public` or be package-private (not explicit, if a variable has no modifier) to be visible within the aforementioned annotations since they exist at the different class. I would like to find out whether it's possible to reduce the scope of the queries to a single class (making them `private`) by means of defining 
 and registering them in Hibernate at the same class.

Answer (score -3):

Use Java Persistence API (JPA) which is a Java specification for accessing, persisting, and managing data between Java objects / classes and a relational database.

Classes that are mentioned in mapping files as well as annotated classes in the JAR that contains the **persistence.xml** file (if it is packed) are registered automatically. If the application is not packed in a JAR yet, ObjectDB (as an extension) automatically registers classes under the classpath root directory that contains the **META-INF/persistence.xml** file. Other classes have to be registered explicitly by using class elements (for single class registration) or jar-file elements (for registration of all the classes in the jar file).

Comment: Dear Tehima, if you copy/paste from other sites (http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit) you need to reference the author/source (just like in a thesis :D )

Comment: By the way, you didn't actually answer his question. It is about  _named queries_.

Comment: @Matt I think you should read question again and then read the resource instead of pasting here. So you would better understand how names queries register outside the class/package.

Comment: I did and I am still convinced that your answer has nothing to do with the question. For instance, your first suggestion to use JPA is pointless since he already does since Hibernate is an implementation of JPA. Have you recognized the three down votes on your answer?